# Do Chie or the Protagonist get a free ATK 90+ weapon early in the game?

Tags: persona-4-golden

After beating Yukiko's Shadow, I went back into the TV World to train up, get more cash, and see if I could get some of my favorite Personas like Titania and Lilim. Going back into Yukiko's Castle, I was warned that there was a powerful Shadow so I went and fought it. After defeating it, I found a fan for Yukiko at the Throne with an ATK value of 90+ which was way better than her current fan (~20 ATK) or the one I was planning on buying her (~30 ATK).

After going back, I thought to talk to Yosuke and learned that I could go back to Saki-sempai's Family Store, where Yosuke's shadow was. Not only did I find an item for a quest, but I also found a pair of spanners as a weapon for him, which were about as strong as Yukiko's fan that I'd previously found.

I went back to Floor 2 of Yukiko's Caste where I'd fought Chie's Shadow, but I couldn't find a free weapon for her. I am wondering whether Chie or the Protagonist get free 90+ ATK weapons like what I have already found with Yukiko and Yosuke? If so, where am I supposed to find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://persona4.wikidot.com/equipment), there is not an extra secret boss for you to fight for Chie.

There is only an extra boss at the same place as the original boss fight for the characters that you had to rescue *from a dungeon* in order to recruit.

> That means: Yukiko Amagi, Kanji Tatsumi, Naoto Shirogane, and Teddie (Teddie's is in the dungeon you rescue Rise Kujikawa from, since Rise is not used for combat and Teddie did not have his own dungeon)

The item you found for Yosuke does not appear to have been from a boss fight, but rather:

> Hidden amongst the boxes of the boss's den

Seems like it was just a collectible, rather than a reward.

Also, just a side note, the weapon you found for Yukiko wouldn't really be considered a *free* weapon, so much as a *bonus* weapon, as you had to beat an extra boss to obtain it.

Comment: coming from a games design perspective i considered Yukiko's weapon *free* rather than a *bonus* under the assumption that if i hack the game to remove that extra boss the item would still be there as i had to search for it, rather than it being a drop from the boss itself. but seeing it from your point of view where i could only get Yukiko's weapon from beating an extra boss does make ti seem to be a bonus for defeating it